# Alternative ways of calculating the principal moment of inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, geometry, moment-of-inertia

Let's say I am given 2x2 masses ($m$ and $m'$ have the same mass, just different coordinates):

$m_1: (-a,b,0)$

$m_1':(a,-b,0)$

$m_2: (a,b,0)$

$m_2': (-a,-b,0)$

Due to symmetry the center of mass is located in the origin. If I want to calculate principal moment of inertia, I usually would diagonalize my inertia tensor:

$\begin{pmatrix}
        b^2(m_1+m_2) & ab(m_1-m_2) & 0 \\
        ab(m_1-m_2) & a^2(m_1+m_2) & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & (a^2+b^2)(m_1+m_2) \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

As you can see, this *really* becomes ugly ... so, is there any other way to diagonalize that matrix?

I thought about rotating my coordinate system, so that $ab(m_1-m_2)$ vanishes, but I don't know how to properly apply that.

Comment: Well in this simpler case there is a nice frame with the masses on the axes that admits a diagonal inertia matrix, that corresponds to rotatin the axes to lie on the masses themselves

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If I use a new frame where $x'$ goes through $m_2$ and $y'$ through $m_1$, my matrix still doesn't become diagonal

Comment: How are you calculating this matrix, because if the axes lie on the masses there wont be diagonal terms

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. $J_{11} = m_2(a^2+b^2)$, $J_{22} = m_1(a^2+b^2)$, $J_{33} = (m_1+m_2)(a^2+b^2) $

I see that $J_{33}$ solves my initial matrix. But if I set in the other 2, I still dont receive $0$...

Comment: Well to truely know ho to reduce the matrix you have to solve the eigenvalue problem and diagonalize it, the eigenvectors give insight on the principle axes.

Comment: Yes, I did it vice versa now. I have my eigenvalues due to change of frame and I want to check that solution for my initial frame. Now only $J_{33}$ can stand this test...

Comment: Yeah what i said before i forgot to take i to account the different coordinates, we alreadt know one principle axis is the z axis,  it remains to find the other two, it helps to solve the eigenvector problem with a vector made of the direction cosines

Comment: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node67.html this site gives a little insite on using direction cosines to solve a problem (an example where z is already a principal axis none he less)

Comment: Well, I have the eigenvalues calculated, but $J_{11}$ and $J_{22}$ don't solve my initial polynom. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well once you have the eigenvalues you may obtain the eigenvectors, these are the principal body axes along which the inertia tensor is diagonal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24554/discussion-between-christian-and-dan).